How to insert a background image in angular 18
Hello guys i am new to angular and i want to insert a background image i tried the absolute and relative path. but it didn't work although the path is correct and i tried to search for solution but still didn't work and here is my code. sorry for the bad grammar.
app.component.html
<div class="bg-cover bg-center h-screen" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + ImagePath + ')'">


app.component.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Balayan';
  ImagePath: string = '/assets/Taho.jpg'; 
}


Make sure you have the assets folder added to the angular.json file, in latest versions of angular, there will be a public folder, where you can store the assets.
angular.json
      "options": {
        "assets": ["src/assets"],
        "index": "src/index.html",

After this, restart the server, so that the app recognizes the added paths.
Also make sure you have defined a proper height and width to your div that has the background image.
import { Component, signal, computed } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [
    `
    .bg-cover {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
  `,
  ],
  imports: [RouterOutlet, CommonModule],
  template: `
        <div class="bg-cover bg-center h-screen" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + ImagePath + ')'">
      `,
})
export class App {
  title = 'Balayan';
  ImagePath: string = '/assets/Taho.jpg';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
